# Bluetooth on raspberry 4 without Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on non-Linux OS and now trying to enable bluetooth on Raspberry Pi 4.

I have some necessary drivers such as: gpio, uart (pl011 and mini-uart), mailbox and expgpio through that mailbox.

To enable bluetooth I make some steps:

- I configure GPIOs as described in Linux's dts to make UART0 connected
  to BT/WiFi chip;
- I set BT_ON expgpio to 1 through mailbox (it is made by default, just ensure);

I wrote some command to UART0 and nothing happened =( UART driver return success and reading command answer is always timeouted.
I think I could forget some step for initialization procedure, but as I can see in Linux log there is only firmware downloading and many commands, such as read device name, can be executed prior to it.
May be I forget to enable some clock source or a regulator, but I don't have any idea where start my research.

There is a part of Raspbian kernel log with additional debug info:

```
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321055] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321093] device class 'bluetooth': registering
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321149] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321158] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321176] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321189] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.321208] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335356] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335377] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered at id 0
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335387] bus: 'serial': add driver hci_uart_h5
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335456] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered at id 2
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335480] bus: 'platform': add driver hci_bcm
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335641] bus: 'serial': add driver hci_uart_bcm
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.335679] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered at id 7
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.337922] Bluetooth: TTY name ttyAMA0
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.338543] Bluetooth: hci_uart_register_dev
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.338599] device: 'hci0': device_add
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.345358] device: 'rfkill1': device_add
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.345497] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol set. Proto H4; id 0
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.345530] Bluetooth: hci_uart_open hci0 5d898f04
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.345543] Bluetooth: hci_uart_setup: START
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.345550] Bluetooth: hci_uart_setup: init speed = 0
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.345557] Bluetooth: hci_uart_setup: oper speed = 0
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.352975] Bluetooth: hci0: type 1 len 3
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.353010] Bluetooth skb:   00000000: 01 03 10 00
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.353026] Bluetooth: hci_uart_write_work written 4
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.353760] Bluetooth: hci0: type 1 len 3
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.353826] Bluetooth skb:   00000000: 01 01 10 00
....
a lot of lines
....
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi btuart[479]: bcm43xx_init
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi btuart[479]: Flash firmware /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM4345C0.hcd
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi btuart[479]: Set Controller UART speed to 3000000 bit/s
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi btuart[479]: Device setup complete
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Configure Bluetooth Modems connected by UART.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Multi-User System.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Reached target Graphical Interface.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[625]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Created slice system-bthelper.slice.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper...
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service: Succeeded.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi bthelper[774]: Raspberry Pi BDADDR already set
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished Raspberry Pi bluetooth helper.
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.490868] Bluetooth: hci0: type 1 len 8
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.490909] Bluetooth skb:   00000000: 01 1c fc 05 01 02 00 01 01
Jan 28 05:17:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.490930] Bluetooth: hci_uart_write_work written 9
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked that the data is being transmitted to the Bluetooth module on the correct serial line, e.g. with an oscilloscope? Which HCI transport layer do you use?

Comment: I thought about oscilloscope, but I don't know how to connect it. Because the full circuitry of the board is not available, and poke an oscilloscope in all paths going to the BT/WiFi chip looks a very laborious task and I would like to use this method the latter.

>> Which HCI transport layer do you use?
Linux use H4 protocol and I try to do so. I analyze H4 proto source code and found that is raw transfer without any encoding. Hope I'm right.

Comment: H4 is a 5-wire Interface. I think that the whole development effort doesn't make sense if you don't know if the UART interface works properly. Have you tried reverse engineering the Linux-related parts of the drivers/code?

Comment: I checked uart4 (it is same as uart0) connected it to my PC with terminal and it is work fine. But I am now sure about cts/rts signals. Fast check in our driver implementation shows no support for it. Perhaps this is the point.

Is it possible just just to replace H4 with H5? Because H5 is 3-wire interface. In chip spec written:

"Access to the FIFOs is conducted through the AHB interface through either DMA or the CPU. The UART supports the Bluetooth 5.0 UART HCI specification: H4, a custom Extended H4, and H5."

Or if chip use H4 I must use H4?

Comment: From the device tree I would expect the UART interface to be 5-wire. 
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f3f19f939c11925dadd3f4776f99f8c278a7017b/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dts?plain=1#L118-L122 <br/>
If I remember correctly, the boot-up sequence for the Bluetooth/WiFi chip is very important, because it is decided there whether the HCI transport runs via SPI or UART.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting. I'll try to log and parse all boot sequence from Linux. I thought that chip does that decision automatically. Thank you very much for the help. I'll return in couple of days with new data.

Comment: Hi. I've returned with partial success. You were right, the problem was with Hardware Flow Control. I have added it's support and bt chip replies me it's name. But now I tried to add firmware downloading to chip and stucked with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For H4 protocol UART with Hardware Flow Control must be used. Adding HFC support to PL011 UART driver resolves the problem.